# How can i pass a search-string to MongoDB in TypeScript and get the according results? (Using denos mongo module)

Tags: typescript, mongodb, deno

I try to implement a very simple backend using deno and it's third party module for mongo to access a MonogoDB.

However using the .find() function i am not able to correctly pass the results through my API.

Here is a generalized version of the function i try to write:

```
getElementbySearch: async (
        { searchKey, response } : {searchKey: ElementSchema, response: any}
        ) => { 
            const results = await elements.find(searchKey)
        if (!results) {
            response.status = 404;
            response.body = {
                success: false,
                message: "No element found",
            };
        return;
        }

        response.status = 200;
        response.body = {
            success: true,
            data: results,
        }; 
    }
```

The rest of the backend is working properly, e.g. i have successfully implemented a getAllElements API.

Trying different searchkeys on a mongoDB does also work just fine.

Comment: I solved the question for myself: 
´´´
const getElementbySearch = async ({
  searchKey, response,
}: {
  searchKey: any; response: any;
}) => {
  const searchedTrails = await trails.find(searchKey).toArray();

...
    };
  }
};
´´´

The two changes i made:
- define the "getElementbySearch" as a const 
- not require a specific interface for the searchKey